# DeclareCiteCommand documentation

Tags: biblatex

I tried to use `\hasfieldannotation[author]{}` in a `\DeclareCiteCommand` but I couldn't make it work.

Could someone link the documentation to `\DeclareCiteCommand`? I couldnt find it in the [Biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\DeclareCiteCommand` is documented in §4.3.1 *Citation Style Files*, p. 181 (in v3.16) of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

The `biblatex` documentation is generally not known for being verbose or very rich in examples, so I always like to have a look at the source code to really understand how commands are (suppose to be) used. Several invocations of `\DeclareCiteCommand` for generic commands can be found [in `biblatex.def`, ll. 2147-2266](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2147-L2266), for style-defined citation commands you want to look in the `.cbx` files (e.g. [`authoryear-comp.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-comp.cbx#L160)).